# How do I add accents to a letter?

Tags: python

I am working on a tool to do automatic Spanish verb conjugation. In one tense, the rule is to accent the last vowel.

While I can create a map to get the accented version of a letter, I was wondering if there is a clean, pythonic way to manipulate characters to add diacritical marks (I think I have the right term).

For example:

```
fue -> fué

presta -> prestá
```

etc.

Comment: There are Unicode combining marks that you can just append to the character. Any good Unicode reference will tell you what they are.

Comment: Link to what @MarkRansom is talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character It would still be nice to see a proper answer with example code though

Comment: @MarkRansom so how to do this in python?

Comment: `u'\u0301'.join('Just add accents to random characters?') == "J́úśt́ ́ád́d́ ́áććéńt́ś ́t́ó ́ŕáńd́óḿ ́ćh́áŕáćt́éŕś?"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on the encoding that you want to use. If you're using Latin encoding, then a character map is the way to go. If you're using Unicode, it could be nicer to use [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character); the unicode character for an acute accent is '\u0301', and it comes after the letter you're applying it to:

```
In [40]: 'fue'+ u'\u0301'
Out[40]: 'fué'
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware that it was just as simple as adding the accent as another character.

Comment: @Pat you need to be careful, Unicode contains multiple accent characters. You need a *combining* character, which [U+0301](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm) is.

Comment: `assert 'fue'+ u'\u0301' == 'fué'` returns an error...

Comment: @tommy.carstensen they're not the same string at a byte-level, they're two different representations of the same string.

Comment: Have a way to convert '´' char to `\u0301`, or other accent?