# Capitalize "i" to "İ" in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to capitalize first letter of "ismail"
when i write `"ismail".title()` it shows: Ismail. I want to seem like "İsmail".
Is there any function for this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727507/how-can-i-convert-unicode-to-uppercase-to-print-it) question help?

Comment: The character you apparently want is an accented capital I. If you start with accented lower case ì you would get the uppercase İ

Comment: @TerryA no, it returns "I" again

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755556/how-do-i-add-accents-to-a-letter

Comment: @GarrGodfrey It is not an accented `i`. The problem is that in Turkish the uppercase for `i` is `İ` and not `I`.